# Internationalisation keyboard support in phonegap html5 apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I am preparing an app in sencha touch and phonegap. In my app , I am providing an option to the user to change language .By default , it is english. Now When user changes to some other language , I change the text present, say like placeholder of input box by code.

But is there anyway , I can change the layout of the keyboard which comes on the screen when user taps on any text  box. ? 
There is no attribute present on the input tag which will tell the device to open the keyboard with the different language?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. The keyboard is itself an app and it's settings aren't reachable. The question is: why? you could launch a settings intent where you ask the user to change their keyboard layout if this is some sort of a language training app or whatever.